# What am I doing that prevents Sinatra from loading OmniAuth when running Ruby 1.8.7

Tags: ruby, sinatra, compatibility, omniauth

OmniAuth is supposed to be 1.8.7 compatible and is Rack based.  I've created a custom strategy for OmniAuth that is somehow making Sinatra when run with Ruby 1.8.7 / REE unhappy.  It works fine with Rails 3 in 1.8.7 or 1.9.2 and it also works properly with Sinatra running on 1.9.2.

The source code for my custom strategy (still somewhat in development) is here:
https://github.com/stevenhaddox/oa-casport

The code for a sample Sinatra application is here:
https://github.com/stevenhaddox/oa-casport-sinatra

Any suggestions as to why the OmniAuth::Builder is unhappy under Ruby 1.8.7 would be greatly appreciated as I'd love to ensure that I support the same Ruby platforms as OmniAuth itself does.

Comment: Checked the dependencies for 1.9 compatibility?

Comment: The dependencies are minimal (httparty, redis, and oa-core). Also, it seems to load fine with Rails 3 under Ruby 1.8.7 so my gut tells me this isn't directly related to another gem's dependencies... Thanks for the idea though.

Comment: What does "unhappy" mean? / How would someone reproduce this error?

Comment: @Steven: sinatra add a number of dependencies too.

Comment: @Denis: Sinatra does add a lot of dependencies, but since the OmniAuth gem is supposed to work properly with Sinatra and Rails in many versions of Ruby I excluded a Sinatra dependency as being a culprit, but rather something in my oa-casport gem code itself most likely.

Comment: @Joshua Cheek: In order to replicate the behavior you'd need to create a parent folder & checkout both git repos linked above into it. Then use RVM to ensure you're using Ruby 1.8.7 / REE and run `$ bundle` inside oa-casport-sinatra to get gem dependencies (and load oa-casport from source you checked out). Then just: `$ bundle exec rackup` to get the error preventing Sinatra from loading.

Comment: You really need to explain what "unhappy" means, what error does it give you? (is "unhappy" even an error?)

Answer (score 0):

> Sinatra does add a lot of dependencies, but since the OmniAuth gem is supposed to work properly with Sinatra and Rails in many versions of Ruby I excluded a Sinatra dependency as being a culprit, but rather something in my oa-casport gem code itself most likely.

In my ruby experience (which is arguably short), don't count on that kind of stuff. A gem may specify `>= x.y` rather than `~> x.y` or whatever is the pickier syntax, and you may very well end up with 1.9 dependency. And even then you may get [surprises](http://blog.majesticseacreature.com/the-rubygems-drama-continues). Check *every* gem involved, always.